# How to prove property of complex powers

Tags: complex-numbers

I have the following problem:

If $b$ is real, prove that $|a^b|=|a|^b$. In this case, $a$ is complex number.

I know the definition of a complex power, $a^b=e^{b\log(a)} $, but I´m not sure how to use it.

Comment: That is not true, because $i^i = e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}}$ whose modulus is clearly different from $|i|^{|i|} = 1$.

Comment: You are right. I made a mistake while writing the problem. It should have said $|a^b|=|a|^b$.

Answer (score 1):

We can express $a$ as $r(\cos \theta + i\sin \theta)$. By De Moivre's Theorem, we have 
$$|a^b| = r^b|\cos b\theta + i\sin b\theta| = |a|^b.$$
The important part was that the absolute value of a complex number is multiplicative.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a=|a|e^{i\theta}$. Then
$$|a^b|=|e^{b \log a}|=|e^{b \log{|a|}+i\theta}|=|e^{b \log{|a|}}e^{i\theta}|=||a|^b|=|a|^b.$$